# Why does Wolfram give the wrong expression?

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I tried to get a general formula for the integrals

$$I(u,v):=\int_0^\pi sin^u(x)cos^v(x) dx$$

and $$J(u,v):=\int_0^{2\pi} sin^u(x)cos^v(x)dx$$

The antiderivate is $0$ for $x=0$, according to Wolfram.

Here the antiderivate according to Wolfram

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(sin(x)%5Eucos(x)%5Ev)

And here the expressions for the antiderivate at the points $\pi$ and $2\pi$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+-(abs(sin(x))%5E(1%2Bu)+cos%5E(1%2Bv)(x)+csc%5E(1%2Bu)(x)+2F1((1-u)%2F2,+(1%2Bv)%2F2,+(3%2Bv)%2F2,+cos%5E2(x)))%2F(1%2Bv)+,+x+tends+to+pi

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+-(abs(sin(x))%5E(1%2Bu)+cos%5E(1%2Bv)(x)+csc%5E(1%2Bu)(x)+2F1((1-u)%2F2,+(1%2Bv)%2F2,+(3%2Bv)%2F2,+cos%5E2(x)))%2F(1%2Bv)+,+x+tends+to+2%2Api

> Apparently, this is not correct. For example, if $u$ and $v$ are odd, the correct result is $0$, whereas the given expressions are not $0$ for any pair $u,v$ with integers $u,v\ge 1$. What is going on ?

Comment: The given anti-derivatives are  definite integrals so are **not** functions of x so, of course, the derivative  with respect to x is 0.

Comment: In general, Stack Exchange handles the `*` character within a link poorly. Usually you can fix this by replacing `*` with `%2A` (that is, by writing out the ASCII encoding of `*` rather than writing the character `*` itself). (And apparently SE let me edit this into your question even though it was only one character removed and 3 inserted.)